# Replace word with special characters before and after word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a word for example "word" and if it has characters ':' before and after I need to replace it by other value;

```
var string = 'some random text :word: some text after';
```

I've tried

```
string = string.replace(/:\\s*(word)\\s*:/g, value);
```

But with no success

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to confuse, but a RegExp literal and a string *of* a RegExp literal will often have differently escaped characters. Because you're using a literal, you don't need to escape every backslash, since RegExp will interpret them properly.

In this case, don't double your backward slashes `\`, since that resolves to matching a plain backslash `\`; you're looking to use just `\s`, which will resolve directly as the escape sequence for any whitespace:

```js
var string = 'some random text :word: some text after';

console.log(string.replace(/:\s*(word)\s*:/g, '_REPLACEMENT_'));
```

If you're looking for *any* word, not just the actual string `word`, then use the RegExp sequence `[a-zA-Z]*` instead of `(word)`, which will match a sequence of any number of alpha characters:

```js
var string = 'some random text :newWord: some text after';

console.log(string.replace(/:\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*:/g, '_REPLACEMENT_'));
```

Comment: @weltschmerz I edited my explanation for clarity, how's that?

Comment: Yup good........

Comment: It's also on me, I misread "shouldn't escape characters like you would in strings" as "shouldn't escape characters at all in regexes, that's only done in strings" whereas you meant "not *like* it's done in strings," as in, "the escaping works differently in strings and regexes," which is, of course, perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the capture group, since you're not copying the word into the replacement.

The escaped backslash will match a literal backslash, but you don't have that in your input. If you want to match whitespace, it should just be `\s`, not `\\s`.

If you want to include the `:` in the result, just concatenate them to the replacement value.

```js
var string = 'some random text :word: some text after';
var value = 'replacement';
string = string.replace(/:\s*word\s*:/g, ':' + value + ':');
console.log(string);
```